# How to recursely catch user input in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

Here is an example what I want.

> ./example.sh

**Home Menu**

```
Please input the choice:
1) do something A
2) do something B
3) do something C
4) exit
```

> user input  ----- 2

**do something , and then we come to Menu B**

```
Please input the choice in B: 
1) do something B1
2) do something B2
3) return to the uplevel/last Menu (Home Menu)
4) return to the Home Menu  
5) exit
```

> user input  ----- 1

**do something , and then we come to Menu B1**

```
Please input the choice in B1:
1) do something B1.1
2) do something B1.2
3) do something B1.3
4) return to the uplevel/last Menu (Menu B)
5) return to the Home Menu             
6) exit
```

> user input  ----- 3

**if there is no further deep menu/choice, do something B1.3 and then go back to menu B1**

```
do something B1.3 done !!

Please input the choice in B1:
1) do something B1.1
2) do something B1.2
3) do something B1.3
4) return to the uplevel/last Menu (Menu B)
5) return to the Home Menu             
6) exit
```

> user input  ----- 6

Not sure if it's clearly, this is what I want via a shell script.

**It always keeps in a loop, has a deep menu, and asks user to choose, exit the script if choose "exit".**

Is there any open program using this style which I can refer to ?

I recall that some switch using this style which has a deep recursive menu to let user choose what to config.

Comment: Requests for sample code are off topic here. Read the section on `case` and `select`. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FullBashGuide#TestsAndConditionals . I'm almost sure you can nest a `select` inside of `select itme ... ; case $ans in ...a) select more .. esac ; done` sort o thing. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate such menus for users? Or are you asking how to automate the interaction with an app which has such menus?

Comment: @sexpect - Expect for Shells  
I'm asking how to generate such menus in a shell script

Comment: I would suggest keep it modular. Maybe have functions or separate scripts for each of the submenus. This way it is manageable. A google search came up with this page, https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Menu_driven_scripts

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415155/310780) on unix.stackexchange has a pretty simple version, and it returns the chosen index as you want. And I've continued my work on the project, finally have multiple-choice working but still ironing out some bugs and there's no choice editing yet. That project is at [github.com/l3laze/sind](https://github.com/l3laze/sind).